# EF Core Any in Any client side evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have list of `OrderInfo` which contains Id of `Product`.
I'd want to load all `Order`s (that has `List<Many2Many>` inside)
which has at least one `Product` with `Id` from my `OrderInfo` list

Basically it is nested `Any` `Any`

The code that I wrote below as proof of concept works fine, but the problem is that when I try to do the same on EF Core then it is being evaluated on client side.

How can I make it to evaluate properly?

```
var list_of_details = new List<OrderInfo> {...};

context
.Orders
.Where(o => o.OrdersProducts.Any(p => list_of_details.Any(d => d.ProductId == p.ProductId)));

public class OrderInfo
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    (...)
}

public class Order
{
    public List<Many2Many> OrdersProducts = new List<Many2Many>();
    (...)
}

public class Product
{
    public List<Many2Many> OrdersProducts = new List<Many2Many>();
    (...)
}

public class Many2Many
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's example in non-ef way, but ugly and just as proof of concept

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class OrderInfo
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int Id;
        public List<Many2Many> OrdersProducts = new List<Many2Many>();
    }


    public class Product
    {
        public int Id;
        public List<Many2Many> OrdersProducts = new List<Many2Many>();
    }

    public class Many2Many
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List of ids that have to be in 'Order' in order to qualify him");
        var list_of_details = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => new OrderInfo(){ ProductId = x}).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list_of_details)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ProductId);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        // setup
        var orders = new List<Order>();
        var order = new Order(){Id = 2};

        var product = new Product()
        {
            Id = 3,
        };

        order.OrdersProducts.Add(new Many2Many()
        {
            Order = order,
            OrderId = order.Id,
            Product = product,
            ProductId = product.Id
        });

        var order2 = new Order(){Id = 3};
        var product2 = new Product()
        {
            Id = 4,
        };

        order2.OrdersProducts.Add(new Many2Many()
        {
            Order = order2,
            OrderId = order2.Id,
            Product = product2,
            ProductId = product2.Id
        });


        var order3 = new Order(){Id = 1};
        var product3 = new Product()
        {
            Id = 5,
        };

        order3.OrdersProducts.Add(new Many2Many()
        {
            Order = order3,
            OrderId = order3.Id,
            Product = product3,
            ProductId = product3.Id
        });


        orders.Add(order);
        orders.Add(order2);
        orders.Add(order3);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // end setup

        foreach (var ord in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Order Id: {ord.Id}");
            Console.Write('\t' + "Product Ids: ");
            foreach (var prod in ord.OrdersProducts)
            {
                Console.Write(prod.ProductId);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();        
        Console.WriteLine("found orders");
        foreach (var item in orders.Where(o => o.OrdersProducts.Any(p => list_of_details.Any(d => d.ProductId == p.ProductId))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
List of ids that have to be in 'Order' in order to qualify him
01234


Order Id: 2
   Products Ids: 3
Order Id: 3
   Products Ids: 4
Order Id: 1
   Products Ids: 5

found orders
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to reduce the list to just the ids,

```
var list_of_details = new List<OrderInfo> {...};
var orderInfoIds = list_of_details.Select(d => d.ProductId);
context
.Orders
.Where(o => o.OrdersProducts.Any(p => orderInfoIds.Contains(p.ProductId)));
```

Comment: Thanks! wow, that was so "simple" (I'll be able to accept soon)

Comment: *One method is …* What is the other? :) Just clarifying the wording, so far this is *the only* method to avoid client evaluation. And `ToList` / `ToArray` are not really needed, `Select` is enough.

Comment: This is the only method I have to offer. @IvanStoev Weren't there some incompatibilities between EF core and select list iterators? Or is that only when reading data into POCOs?